# Make button on next row on small screens, but keep in same row on larger screen in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I feel like this should be simple, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it:

I want to create a sticky bottom-bar (essentially a cookie warning bar) with two lines of text and a button. On desktop I want the button to appear right next to the sentence, but on mobile I want it to jump on to the next line.

What would be a good and simple way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post some code and create a Minimal, Reproducible Example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you use the grid system with `col` inside `row` and choose what size you need your content to change. Here is a link to a solution using bootstrap: https://codepen.io/DohaHelmy/pen/vYEjXzO

and the following is a solution without bootstrap classes but the same functionality of bootstrap grid system.

```css
#cookies {
  background-color: #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

p {
  padding: 20px;
}

button {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #357832;
  border: none;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 576px) {
  #cookies {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="cookies">
  <p>consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ull</p>
  <button>aciton</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That makes sense and works like a charm! Thanks for taking your time to suggesting it!